# How to convert `tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_file` into Tensorflow v2

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm new to Tensorflow and working on code from v1 Tensorflow, but `tf.contrib` module is no longer supported in Tensorflow and I'm facing trouble finding their substitute in V2.
I disabled V2 with this code :

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

But still it is not working for `tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_file` and I'm getting an error 
`AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.compat.v1' has no attribute 'contrib'`. I tried looking in their official documentation [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) but couldn't find one.

What is the substitute for  `tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_file` function in V2?

Comment: Can you try using `tf.python.ops.lookup_ops.index_table_from_file` and let us know if its helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `tf.lookup.StaticVocabularyTable` to achieve the same.
If you want to bring index and value from TextFile you can use `tf.lookup.TextFileInitializer` within `tf.lookup.StaticVocabularyTable`.

Below is an example.

```
num_oov_buckets = 3
input_tensor = tf.constant(["emerson", "lake", "palmer", "king", "crimnson"])
table = tf.lookup.StaticVocabularyTable(
    tf.lookup.TextFileInitializer(
        filename,
        key_dtype=tf.string, key_index=tf.lookup.TextFileIndex.WHOLE_LINE,
        value_dtype=tf.int64, value_index=tf.lookup.TextFileIndex.LINE_NUMBER,
        delimiter="\t"),
    num_oov_buckets)
out = table.lookup(input_tensor)
```

You can follow this [Official Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lookup/StaticVocabularyTable) from Tensorflow for more details.